# Why does maven ignores the JDK i installed?

Tags: java, maven

When I do anything with Maven (using `mvn` command) I get the following message:

> The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly This
>   environment variable is needed to run this program NB: JAVA_HOME
>   should point to a JDK not a JRE

```
java -version
```

returns the following:

> openjdk version "1.8.0_212-1-ojdkbuild"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-1-ojdkbuild-b04)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)

My JAVA_HOME points at the bin folder of this JDK. 
My PATH variable also has the same bin folder in it.

My question is what am I doing wrong? Shouldnt `java -version` say Development kit instead of Runtime enviroment?

Comment: JAVA_PATH is not a thing. You need to define JAVA_HOME to point to the root folder of your Java installation e.g. /home/user/java/1.8.0_212-1-ojdkbuild

Comment: You can also add JAVA_HOME\bin (or JAVA_HOME/bin) to your path. That makes the java executable available everywhere and that's how java -version can work

Comment: @DavidBrossard misswrote it in the question, but i have it as JAVA_HOME in variables

Comment: JAVA_HOME should point at the folder above the bin folder.

Comment: @matt tried it like that, but same behaviour, also previously it worked with /bin being there

Comment: Did you set it OS-wide? It could be mvn doesn't see the environment variable. BTW what OS are you on?

Comment: @DavidBrossard WIndows 10 and under system variable. There is JAVA_HOME with correct path

Comment: @matt i restarted both the CLI and the computer itself

Comment: @matt echo  works, returns correct path but %JAVA_HOME%/bin/java -version returns this: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @KristófHorváth I think you can use quotes, also I switched the slashes in an edit. ( I haven't used windows in a long time.

Comment: What do you get when you run `javac -version` ?

Comment: @matt echo works so the path is correct to the installed jdk.

Comment: "%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\java should work. If not, it seems the java home is looks ok, but something is wrong.

Comment: @StephenC i get the version of the installed JDK

Comment: For `javac` too?

Comment: @StephenC for just javac, i get the usage message

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we are going to work out what the problem by asking you questions.  Instead I suggest you do the following:

1. At the command prompt, set the environment variable `%MAVEN_BATCH_ECHO%` to the value `on`.  Then at the same command prompt, run `mvn`.  This is supposed to echo all commands that the `mvn.cmd` batch file runs.
2. Compare the output with the source of the batch file ... as installed on your system.  In particular, see what gets echo'd for these lines:

   ```
   @REM ==== START VALIDATION ====
   if not "%JAVA_HOME%"=="" goto OkJHome
   for %%i in (java.exe) do set "JAVACMD=%%~$PATH:i"
   goto checkJCmd

   :OkJHome
   set "JAVACMD=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"

   :checkJCmd
   if exist "%JAVACMD%" goto chkMHome

   echo The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly >&2
   echo This environment variable is needed to run this program >&2
   echo NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE >&2
   goto error
   ```

   (Note that the above excerpt is taken from the most recent version of the Maven batch file does.  You may have an older version of Maven that does something different.  Check it before jumping to conclusions.)
3. If that doesn't work, modify the batch file and add a line to `echo` what `%JAVA_CMD%` is set to.   Then run the modified batch file.

Note that the validation is actually checking that `%JAVA_CMD%` exists as a file.

---

I see you have actually solved the problem by reinstalling.  Unfortunately, that doesn't tell us what the problem really was.

Answer (score 1):

`JAVA_HOME` should refer to folder where `bin` folder is located, but I think you have installed inly java, without jdk, run `javac -version` you will see if compiler is available.

Probably you should install package `openjdk-8-jdk`, but you have only `openjdk-8-jre`.  Thats ubuntu package names. Name can be different depending on your OS.

Comment: javac return: javac 1.8.0_212
Also the version I installed previously worked and is currently being used by a friend.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have installed JDK under `C:\Program Files\...` and therefore you need to put the absolute path in both, `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` environment variables i.e. do not set `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` in `PATH`; rather, set `C:\Program Files\...\bin` in `PATH` environment variable.

Also, make sure the path set in `JAVA_HOME` is one level above the path set in `PATH` variable.

Last but not the least, make sure you move the path of this JDK above all values under `PATH` which will make sure that the path of another JDK does not take precedance over the JDK which you want to work with.

Comment: i have the full path both in PATH and JAVA_HOME

Comment: If the path was wrong, then java -version wouldn't work.

Comment: @matt - This is not correct. `java -version` may also point to JRE. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GDRAD/java.htm#BGBFHBEA) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalling everything and clearing directories and computer restart. I reinstalled everything. In System variables PATH is set to java path + /bin and on JAVA_HOME its just the path to the folder.
MAven is operational again